# Sistema para identificar que o usuário é dono do tópico PHP + Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

BOA TARDE.
Eu estou fazendo um fórum de ajudas em meu site, e me deparei com uma dúvida.
Tentei fazer com que, quando o dono do tópico estivesse com a dúvida respondida, ele mesmo pudesse fechar o tópico. Porém, estou com certa mensagem ao tentar exibir a mensagem para ele clicar.
Eu tentei isso:

```
    <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        $db = mysql_select_db('registro');
        $id = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT `Autor` FROM topicos WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
    $limite = mysql_query("$sql");
    if ($sql = $login_cookie ) { // o $login_cookie é minha variavel que seleciona o nome de usuário, quando ele está ativo na conta
// então, tentei comparar o nome de usuário com o nome do autor do tópico
        echo "Fechar tópico";
    } else {
        echo "oi"; // mensagem só para certificar se funcionou
    }
    ?>
```

Porém não obtive resultados.

Eu não quero um código completo, apenas quero saber como poderia fazer, ou seja, de que maneira eu poderia fazer.

Bom, através dessa edição, venho falar que esse sistema me ajudaria em diversas outras funções também do meu fórum.
Eu esqueci de informar também o que está acontecendo:
Colocando esse código, aparece a mensagem independente de quem esteja logado.
Não sei se uma imagem deve ajudar, mas acredito que mostre melhor o que faço: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgF98.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `if` são dois sinais de `=` para fazer comparação.
Você não havia pegado o resultado da sua `query`, para isso usei o `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db = mysql_select_db('registro');
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "SELECT Autor FROM topicos WHERE ID = $id";
    $limite = mysql_query($sql);
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($limite);

    if ($res['Autor'] == $login_cookie ) { 
        echo "Fechar tópico";
    } else {
        echo "oi";
    }
?>
```

Verificação no mesmo `SELECT`:

`SELECT Autor FROM topicos WHERE ID = $id AND Autor = '$login_cookie'`;

Você está verificando acima se o tópico específico foi criado pelo Autor do usuário logado.

Daí você faz outra verificação perguntando quantas linhas foram retornadas. Nesse caso deve se retornar 1 ou 0.

Então:

```
$limite = mysql_query($sql);
$numlinha = mysql_num_rows($limite);

if($limite == 1)
    echo "Criou";
else
    echo "Não criou";
```

Comment: Tentarei aqui e já já posto resultados. Obrigado pela resposta, desde já.

Comment: Funcionou direitinho. Obrigado amigo. Resumindo: eu precisava pegar o resultado da querry, ao invés de tentar comparar o select e por dois sinais de igualdade na comparação, certo?

Comment: Sim. Saber o certo é importante, mas é importante também que você entenda o que fez de errado. Além disso, tem várias formas de fazer essa verificação. Essa é uma delas e até mesmo não é a mais indicada. Você pode fazer tudo no mesmo `SELECT`.

Comment: Obrigado. Mais uma vez